# What is the equivalent of svn log -v in TFS?

Tags: svn, tfs, azure-devops

This is the verbose output of recent changes of an svn repository from the `svn log -v` command

```
r22 | dev_0 | 2013-03-26 15:54:08 +0530 (Tue, 26 Mar 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /Adhoc_Requests/Cust_1/SupplyExtract.sql

added SupplyExtract.sql based on the adhoc request
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Contractor_0 | 2013-02-19 02:20:26 +0530 (Tue, 19 Feb 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /Application
   A /Adhoc_Requests
   A /Adhoc_Requests/Cust_2
   A /Adhoc_Requests/Cust_2/MaleFemaleCounts.sql
   A /Adhoc_Requests/Cust_1
   A /Adhoc_Requests/Cust_1/DomainScores.sql

Initial commit
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get same for a TFS repository?

PS: TFS is not installed in my machine or in my network. I just use the online Team Foundation Service.

Comment: Ins't it just the same as using the `History` point of the `Source Control Explorer`?

Comment: `View History` only displays `Changeset  User  Date  Comment`. It doesn't display the changeset details. Yes, I know I can do `View Changeset Details`, but with an option like `svn log -v` I would be able to view multiple changeset details at once.

Comment: Maybe this will help you a little bit then because I suppose you want to see it in a command window? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w51xa47k(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `tf history` command which might be what you're looking for.

Open up a visual studio command prompt and navigate to your workspace (this saves you having to add a bunch of paramiters to tell TFS what server / team project etc that you want to talk to)

the use something like

`tf history $/TeamProject/Branch/Folder /format:detailed /noprompt /recursive`

/noprompt stops the tool bringing up the GUI and shows the results in the CLI

/recursive navigates the whole tree rather than just the directory provided